# Что означает этот код ( запятые в квадратных скобках )

Tags: javascript

```
gulp.src(globs[, options])
orchestrator.add(name[, deps][, function]);
```

Выше две строчки кода, выдернутого из двух разных хелпов.
 Что они означают? Могу лишь догадываться, но хочется услышать Вашу, правильную интерпретацию запятых в квадратных скобках.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эти строки из документации и означают, что данные параметры необязательны.

Answer (score 5):

Дополню ответ [[@RubaXa](/users/12604/rubaxa)](/users/12604/rubaxa). Подобный синтаксис появился задолго до JavaScript, и в общем случае выглядит так (на примере командной строки, не всё это относится к аргументам функций и методов - *возможны вариации*, но для общей картины):

- в угловых скобках указываются обязательные параметры: `ping <hostname>`
- в квадратных скобках - необязательные: `mkdir [-p] <dirname>`
- три точки обозначают повторяющиеся параметры (или набор из нескольких однотипных, или переменное число аргументов): `cp <source1> [source2...] <dest>`
- допустимые значения параметра обозначаются так: `netstat {-t|-u}`

Comment: А вот тут вопрос про курицу и яйцо, что появилось раньше. Всё же думаю, подобная нотация появилась раньше в программировании, чем command line.

Comment: Что до появления JS - это уж всяко, но я и не утверждал, что JS и "программирование" это одно и то же, и что ком. строка первична. Помнится, где-то в дебрях древней документации к ARJ первых версий встречал историческую справку про этот синтаксис, но точно не помню.